# How to read timestamp from excel list in python

Tags: python, excel, timestamp, timedelta

I am quite new to python and already struggling with an easy task like importing the timestamps of a series of measurement from an excel list. 
The excel file has one column for date and one for time. I need the data for further calculation like time difference etc.

I tried to different ways how to get the data. So far my codes looks like this:

1. method with pyexcel

   ```
   import pyexcel as pe
   import datetime
   import time
   from datetime import time
   import timestring

   for n in range(len(users)):
       sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name=users[n],name_columns_by_row=0)
       sheet = sheet.to_array()
       data_meas = np.array(sheet)

       for row in range(len(data_meas)):
           print(type(row))
           input_time = data_meas[row,1]
           input_date = data_meas[row,0]
           times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, input_time, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")]
   ```

   I get this error for the last line:

   > TypeError: strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
2. method with xlrd

   ```
   import xlrd
   from datetime import time
   inputdata = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls')
   sheet = inputdata.sheet_by_index(0)
   for row in sheet:
       input_date=sheet.cell_value(row,0)
       input_time=sheet.cell_value(row,1)
       date_values = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(input_time, inputdata.datemode)
   time_value = time(*date_values[3:])
   ```

   > TypeError: 'Sheet' object is not iterable

Does anybody know how to help me?
I appreciate every hint.

Comment: For your first approach: concatenate `input_date`and `input_time` to a single string: `strptime(input_date + " " + input_time, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. 
Now it is saying: 
ValueError: time data 'Date Time' does not match format '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
           In the excel file i put the date as DD/MM/YYYY and time as HH:MM:SS

Comment: Make sure the format you pass matches the concatenated string. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Then your format string should look sth like this: `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`

Comment: I am getting closer to the answer I guess.. but still not right. Now: TypeError: Can't convert 'datetime.time' object to str implicitly

Comment: If I put the date and the time in one cell in the excel list to avoid the string error, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first solution, `strptime` takes only one date string as input.
You should join `input_date` and `input_time`:

```
input_time = '18:20:00'
input_date = 'Mon, 30 Nov 2015'
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(' '.join([input_date, input_time]), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

To create the whole list of `datetime` objects, you can try:

```
times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(' '.join([data_meas[row,0], data_meas[row,1]]), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") for row in range(len(data_meas))]
```

**Edit:**

If you want to keep the `for loop`, you have to append each `datetime` object to your list (otherwise you will only keep the last date):

```
data_meas = np.array([['07/11/2015 18:20:00'],['09/11/2015 21:20:00']])

#list initilization
times = []

for row in range(len(data_meas)): 
    input_date = data_meas[row,0] 
    #we add a new item to our list
    times.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Now, you can access each `datetime` in the list `times`. To calculate time differences, you can check the documentation on [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

```
#Create a timedelta object
t1 = times[1] - times[0]
#Convert time difference in seconds
t2 = t1.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Actually I want to create a whole list of the timestamps so that i can calculate the time difference between different rows. What might make it even more complicated is that I have several series of measurements as there are many users. 
With your last code I get this error TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, datetime.time found

Comment: Something might go wrong with the `join`. The code works fine for me on 
`data_meas = np.array([['Mon, 30 Nov 2015','18:20:00'],['Sat, 09 Nov 2015','21:20:00']])` 
Can you maybe update the question with the current version of your code please?

Comment: This code is working except that i cannot call times by index. do you have an idea how to call the timestamp of each row to calculate the time differnce whenever I need it?
for n in range(len(users)):
    sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name=users[n],name_columns_by_row=0)
    sheet = sheet.to_array()
    data_meas = np.array(sheet)
    
    for row in range(len(data_meas)-2):
        #input_time = data_meas[row+2,1]
        input_date = data_meas[row+2,0]

        times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")] 
    times=np.array(times)
    delta = times[2]-times[1]